# Suma consecutivas

Tags: java

Hola estoy aprendiendo a programar y tuve que hacer un còdigo que sume varios  nùmeros pero cuando lo corro se queda trabado despues de poner la cantidad de nùmeros a sumar, alguien sabe donde me equivoque.

aqui el codigo:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Suma{
    public static void main (String [] args) {
   Scanner entrada = new Scanner( System.in);
     int s = 0;
     int suma = 0;
      int n=0;
     String salida= "";

  System.out.println(" Cuanto numeros deseas sumar");
         n =  entrada.nextInt();  
     while( s<=n);{
        suma = suma+s; 
           s= s+1;}


System.out.println( salida+ " El resultado es " +suma);
}
}
```

Comment: Elimina el `;` inmediatamente después del `while( s<=n)`

Comment: Muchas gracias era eso

Answer (score 0):

Este deberia ser el orden de tu codigo.

```
public class Suma {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int numero = 0, acu = 0, suma = 0, n;
        String salida = "";

        System.out.println("Cuanto numeros deseas sumar: ");
        n = entrada.nextInt();
        while (acu < n) {
            System.out.println("Dame un numero: ");
            numero = entrada.nextInt();
            suma = suma + numero;
            acu++;
        }

        System.out.println(" El resultado es " + suma);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EL problema fundamental es error de sintaxis `while( s<=n);{`, luego de los parentesis va el inicio de la llave y no un (**;**).
PD: Aquí te dejo algunos consejos que te facilitaran la vida:

- En vez de escribir `s= s+1;` puedes escribir esto `s++;` incrementará en 1 **s** pero al terminar de leer la sentencia o puedes escribir `++s;` que es lo al revés
- Al igual que en vez de `suma = suma+s;` puedes escribir `suma += s;` hará lo mismo
- Si no vas a escribir nada en la variable **salida** no es necesario que la pongas `System.out.println( salida+ " El resultado es " +suma);`ni que la declares, solo estás ocupando espacio en memoria innecesariamente `System.out.println(" El resultado es " +suma);` puedes hacerlo así

Answer (score 0):

cuando pones el  while( s<=n); lo que interpreta el compilador es un  while( s<=n){}
para este tipos de recorridos te recomiendo usar un bucle for, ya que tienes que recorrer todos los elementos siempre, le he hecho unos pequeños cambios, a ver si te sirve de algo.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Suma{
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner( System.in);
        System.out.println("Cuanto numeros deseas sumar");
        int  sumaTotal = 0,cantidadNumeros =  entrada.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i < cantidadNumeros; i++) {
            System.out.println("Pon el "+(i+1)+"º Numero que quieres sumar.");
            sumaTotal+= entrada.nextInt();
        }
        System.out.println("El resultado es " +sumaTotal);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Prueba con esto en la ultima linea, tal vez el error es porque sumas y concatenas al mismo tiempo, es decir utilizas el signo + para String y int

System.out.println(" El resultado es " + (suma));